# Showing my website in a users language

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a small search engine site and I was wondering if there was any way of displaying my site in the users language. I am looking for an inventive and quick way that can also reside on just one URL.

I hope you can understand my question.

Comment: Because the question isn't asked very well i am guessing!

Comment: Jukka has some [good general advice about multilingual websites](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/multi/index-en.htm)

Comment: Seemed obvious what was being asked to me.

Comment: IMHO, it seems [off-topic as per the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [**HTTP header**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) "**`Accept-Language`**", to detect which languages the user has choosen as its prefered ones, in his browser.

In PHP, this will be available *(if sent by the browser)* in **`$_SERVER`**, which is an array that contains *(amongst other things)* HTTP headers sent by the client.

This specific header should be available as `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

Comment: Don't assume it is going to be accurate though. (e.g. Alice may be on holiday overseas and using a computer in a cybercafe). Take accept-language as a default, but allow it to be overridden.

Comment: @Callum : the browser will load what you sent it -- up to you to generate the right content, once you have detected the language ;; and Quentin is true : this must be used as a default, that can be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you already have different versions of the site in various languages. Most sites seem to just ask the user what their language is and then save that in a cookie. You can probably guess a users language using an ip to location tool.

You are probably more interested in this though: http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php_language_detection.php. This php script allows you to detect the users language based on info sent from their browser. It might not be completely accurate though, so you should always have an option to switch the language.

If you don't have translations of your page, you can redirect users to a google translate page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy solution for this. Just use Google's Translate Elements JS addon. You drop the JS on the page and Google takes care of the rest.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

The only downside is that they cannot fully interact with the site using this. By that I mean they cannot input something in their own language and you get back the input in yours. Also searches will have to be done in the sites native language. So really this just depends on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script which checks for a language cookie.

If language-cookie is set, you can use that value for using the right language-vars, 
if not you find out the users current language by a way, you prefer. I think there are lot of ways, dont know which is the best.

Additional you would place a form somewhere on the site, where the user can klick a language, and u give that by post to a script which then sets a cookie, or overwrites the current cookie, if there is one allready.
This method obviously works with one url for all your languages, which i think is quite nice about it...